# Timezone conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript

I there any way to convert datetime from one timezone to another in javascript.

I need to convert UTC to BST in javascript.

currently am getting the time in IST and converting it to UTC, but am not getting the BST time as required.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer might help you..

[TimeZone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)